# In Android Studio "Show In Explorer" link redirects/takes to wrong folder (library\ build than app\build) in Windows File Explorer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I have been using Android Studio for quite some time now
And every time I click on

- Build and
- Build apk

The Successfully generated APK dialog appears like below:
 [image: Build APK dialog]

But here the "**Show in Explorer**" Hyperlink redirects/takes me to the wrong folder in windows file explorer

It should have taken me to `app\build` folder
But it takes me to  `library\build` folder

I am using `Android Studio 2.3.3` and this has been the same for the past 2 - 3 versions of `Android Studio` now.

Any Idea if this can be corrected ?

Comment: sounds like a possible bug. I suggest reporting it to the Android Studio team. (Don't have a link for their bug tracker. I hope you can find something via google.)

Comment: I face the same issue and google it but didn't find any solution for this issue. We just hope Android Studio team resolve this issue from new version.

Comment: I also couldn't find anything.. As suggested by @Code-Apprentice lets report it to the team

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63517645